# Synchronize an Eclipse project with Google Drive

Tags: java, eclipse, google-drive-api

i've tried to sync a project doing the same steps this guide suggests: http://blog.utahcon.com/computers/cloud-storage/dropbox-eclipse-awesome

It works but on my laptop, when i open the project, there's something wrong. I'm not really good with Eclipse or Java but i think it can't find the compiler because everything is underlined in red, as if it couldn't find libraries or something else.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Can u put the error details.You can see that under Window->Show View -> Error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have same workspace and JDK location on every pc you sunchronize with google drive. Obviously, you have different paths to jdk and/or other important libraries(e.g. external libraries configured in eclipse for this project). Or you just don't have JDK installed on your second pc. Please give us a screenshot, so we could understand which libraries you are missing.